# Consistent increases and decreases in iPerf TCP throughput

Tags: testing, networking, tcp, wifi, iperf

I am using iPerf to try and test the Wi-Fi performance on my router. I have set up two computers, a HP Zbook (Client) and a Macbook Pro (Server), to demonstrate this connection. The client is connected directly to the router via LAN and the server is connected to the router via Wi-Fi.

My iPerf script sets the TCP window size and sends data for certain time limits from the client to the server. The output on my server goes up to an expected throughput for a few seconds and down to a very low throughput for a few seconds at relatively constant intervals for all Wi-Fi configurations on my router (various bands, 802.11 protocols and channel bandwidths) as well as in noisy and clean environments. Can anyone suggest a possible reason for this? Is this how the Wi-Fi protocol works? Or is this a problem with iPerf?

The iperf version on the client is iperf3 v3.0.11 (windows 64 bit) and iperf3 v3.0.1 (mac osx).

Client OS: Windows 10

Server OS: Mac OS X El Capitan v 10.11.5

I have ran a TCP test as well as two UDP tests (with bandwidth set to 1.05Mbps and 150Mbps) and attached the output screenshots. Wi-Fi config: 802.11ac, 40MHz, 5GHz

[jPerf depiction of my iPerf script for a 180 second test case on 5GHz, 80MHz, 802.11ac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhMFq.png)

Testing screenshots: https://imageshack.com/a/SktM/1

Comment: Wi-Fi is a shared medium, and it must yield to other devices using the same frequency (you don't own the airwaves).

Comment: @Ron, except it still decreases in throughput when there is no interference.

Comment: Are you conducting a wireless site survey to determine that? If your WAP can hear any other device on that frequency, it will periodically yield. That is what it sounds like is happening. Wi-Fi is a half-duplex medium. The WAP and the client cannot be transmitting at the same time, and the client must stop for the WAP, and the WAP must stop for the client. TCP requires two-way communication, so the client must periodically stop for the WAP, and anything else that may be on that frequency. That is the nature of Wi-Fi.

Answer (score 0):

Please include the iperf output for both client and server and use interval reports (-i).  Also, include iperf -v and the operating system information.    Also, make a run with UDP and capture the reports on both client and server.  If you're using Linux on the client and iperf 2.0.9, the -e (enhanced reports) can provide even more information.

Wi-Fi throughput problems are like somebody having a fever in an Emergency Room.  There are many different factors that have to be looked at.

Bob